# How to Create a Specific Time From Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table with `Time` data type column, which stores times from users (via `f.time_select` form helper). It works fine when I input time through the form, but I can't create a time object from rails irb console with `.create` or `.new`. The message is:

> irb(main):003:0> Sleep.create(hours: "1970-01-01 06:15:00")
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: Time columns will become time zone aware in Rails
>   5.1. This still causes `String`s to be parsed as if they were in `Time.zone`, and `Time`s to be converted to `Time.zone`.
>
> To keep the old behavior, you must add the following to your
>   initializer:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
> ```
>
> To silence this deprecation warning, add the following:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]  (called from irb_binding at (irb):3) DEPRECATION WARNING: Time columns
> ```
>
> will become time zone aware in Rails 5.1. This still causes `String`s
>   to be parsed as if they were in `Time.zone`, and `Time`s to be
>   converted to `Time.zone`.
>
> To keep the old behavior, you must add the following to your
>   initializer:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
> ```
>
> To silence this deprecation warning, add the following:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
> ```

I was trying to add each of these lines to the `config/application.rb` under `class Application < Rails::Application` and then try different syntaxis combinations to create time through irb, like `Sleep.create(hours: "1970-01-01", "06:20:00")` but nothing worked.

I'm also getting results like this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> irb(main):003:0> Sleep.create(hours: "1970-01-01 06:15:00")
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
irb(main):003:0> Sleep.create(hours: "19
```

or

```
Sleep.create(hours: "1970-01-01", "06:15:00")
irb(main):002:0> Sleep.create(hours: "1970-01-01", "06:15:00")
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
urs: "1970-01-01", "06:15:00")
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I create some particular time from irb?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444164/how-to-create-a-new-datetime-object-in-a-specific-time-zone-preferably-the-defa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new DateTime object in a specific time zone (preferably the default time zone of my app, not UTC)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444164/how-to-create-a-new-datetime-object-in-a-specific-time-zone-preferably-the-defa)